# How to connect an external postgresql database to Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building an application that uses Django for the backend, connecting to an external postgreSQL. 
Currently, I was able to load the database to django ORM using inspectdb command, serialize the data in Django Rest and display in React.

I am worried about what happens if the external database is updated, I am not doing any writing into the database but displaying the data. If the database is updated externally, would it update in my django ORM automatically. My assumption was that wouldn't work. Correct me if I am wrong about that.

I have two questions about this :

1. Is it possible to connect the external database to django rest framework without touching the ORM and as well ensure automatic update incase the external database gets updated? Note that no writes, updates are to be performed, just displaying the data.
2. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean the external database is updated like a new column is added/removed or some other schema change?

Comment: I think you want something like [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/).

Comment: @schillingt yes I mean like additional data added to the tables on the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it will affect much. The ORM is just translating python code to sql query and query the database. If a new table A or column is added to the database, but your application doesn't need table A, then you don't have to change your code. If there is changes to the database that will break the code (Ex. removing a table/column), then you will have to modify your ORM model and application logic.

If you are talking about inserting/deleting data, the ORM will see the changes when it queries the database, so this is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks Joey. This really gives me the confidence that I don't have to worry about inserted/deleted data. 
So I am taking that if a table/column is added or removed, I'll have to run an ./manage.py inspectdb command inorder to stay up to date with the database columns and tables.